# Validation that returns more than 1 error

Tags: scala

I'm doing a few validations using an older Scala version (2.0) but for each record I am currently getting only 1 error, assuming the record has 2 or more error -- I want to receive everything wrong with that record/item

```
case class Response(request: JsValue,
    success: Boolean,
    column: Option[String] = None,
    message: String = "")
```

Here is validator, that return all errors in a json object

```
def validator(asJson: JsValue): Response = {
  if (name == "")
    return Response(asJson, false, Some("name"), "Name can't be blank")
  if (age == -1 || age == "N/A")
    return Response(asJson, false, Some("age"), "Age can't be blank")
  if (DOB == -1 || DOB == "N/A" )
    return Response(asJson, false, Some("DOB"), "DOB cannot be blank")
  else
    Response(asJson, true)
}
```

Currently if `record1` doesn't have a name + age + DOB ---> I'm only getting "Name can't be blank"

How do I get (multiple errors per item instead of just 1 error per item):

*Name can't be blank, Age can't be blank, DOB cannot be blank*

Comment: You return the response with the error message right away. If you want to aggregate your errors, you might want to store tehm in a `List` and return that list.

Comment: @tgr interesting! I'm open to see different approach/solutions to this, could you please share a snippet of your solution? thanks!

Comment: The answer of @Tim pretty much does it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just an outline of how it might work:

```
def validator(asJson: JsValue): Response = {
  val errors = List(
    if (name == "" ) Some("Name can't be blank") else None,
    if (age == -1 || age == "N/A") Some("Age can't be blank") else None,
    if (DOB == -1 || DOB == "N/A" ) Some("DOB cannot be blank") else None,
  ).flatten

  if (errors.isEmpty) {
    Response(asJson, true)
  } else {
    Response(asJson, false, errors.mkString(", "))
  }
}
```

The `errors` value is created by making a `List` of `Option` values, one for each validation check. The `flatten` method extracts the contents of all the `Some` values and removes any `None` values. The result is a list of error strings.

The rest of the code formats the `Response` based on the list of errors.

---

If you are using Scala 2.13 then `Option.when` makes the tests shorter and clearer:

```
Option.when(name == "")("Name can't be blank"),
Option.when(age == -1 || age == "N/A")("Age can't be blank"),
Option.when(DOB == -1 || DOB == "N/A")("DOB cannot be blank"),
```

Comment: yes I had used option.when() but I'm still running on a older scala version

Comment: I understand the expected is Option:[String] .... what if the actual is :String ?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand what you are asking, but you can turn `String` into `Option[String]` by using `Some(string)`.

Comment: thanks ...errors.mkString(", ")... was giving me an exception "Type mismatch,expected expected:Option[String],actual:String" ....

Comment: You must understand that `Option[T]` allows to perform validations on objects of type `T`.

Comment: Ah, OK, I messed up the signature of `Response`, I missed out the `Option[String]` parameter, should be something like `Response(asJson, false, None, Some(errors.mkString(", "))`. (Not sure what that `None` should be)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in scala you do not have the `return` statement, the last statement is returned (in fact it exists but its use is not recomended).

Secondly, in your code, I suppose you want to pass through several `if` statements. But if you return after each `if` statement you exit your function at the first condition that is true, and you will never go to the rest of the code.

If you want to gather several instances of `Response`, just gather them in a collection, and return the collection at the end of the function. A collection might be a `List`, or a `Seq`, or whatever.

Comment: Scala does have a `return` statement, but it does not always work as expected and is not recommended for normal code.

Comment: @Catalina Noted! I'm new to scala and very open to learning the do's and don't

Comment: @Tim Yes, of course, I was about to modify it. Return exists but is never used. I entirely agree with what you write.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GGe70xPVS7yuaNB1ERaZHQ) is an alternative using [`Validated`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html) that you might consider at some point

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import cats.data.ValidatedNec
import cats.implicits._

case class User(name: String, age: Int, dob: String)
case class UserDTO(name: Option[String], age: Option[Int], dob: Option[String])
implicit val userDtoFormat = Json.format[UserDTO]
val raw =
  """
    |{
    |  "name": "Picard"
    |}
    |""".stripMargin
val userDto = Json.parse(raw).as[UserDTO]

def validateUser(userDto: UserDTO): ValidatedNec[String, User] = {
  def validateName(user: UserDTO): ValidatedNec[String, String] =
    user.name.map(_.validNec).getOrElse("Name is empty".invalidNec)

  def validateAge(user: UserDTO): ValidatedNec[String, Int] =
    user.age.map(_.validNec).getOrElse("Age is empty".invalidNec)

  def validateDob(user: UserDTO): ValidatedNec[String, String] =
    user.dob.map(_.validNec).getOrElse("DOB is empty".invalidNec)

  (validateName(userDto), validateAge(userDto), validateDob(userDto)).mapN(User)
}

validateUser(userDto)
// res0: cats.data.ValidatedNec[String,User] = Invalid(Chain(Age is empty, DOB is empty))
```

Note the distinction between `UserDTO` ("data transfer object") which models whatever payload was sent over the wire, and `User` which models the actual data we require for our business logic. We separate the concern of user validation into its own method `validateUser`. Now we can work with valid user or errors like so

```
validateUserDTO(userDto) match {
  case Valid(user) =>     
    // do something with valid user

  case Invalid(errors) => 
    // do something with errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code I've simple Validator that does exactly that:

```scala
abstract class Validator[T, ERR >: Null] {
  def validate(a:T):Seq[ERR]
  protected def is(errorCase:Boolean, err: => ERR) = if (errorCase) err else null
  protected def check(checks:ERR*) = checks.collectFirst{ case x if x != null => x }.getOrElse(null)
  protected def checkAll(checks:ERR*) = checks.filter(_ != null)
}

//implement checks on some types
val passwordValidator = new Validator[String, String] {
  val universalPasswordInstruction = "Password needs to have at least one small letter, big letter, number and other sign."
  def validate(a: String) = checkAll( //here we check all cases
    is(a.length < 10, "Password should be longer than 10"),
    check( //here we check only first one.
      is(a.forall(_.isLetter), s"Passowrd has only letters. $universalPasswordInstruction"),
      is(a.forall(_.isLetterOrDigit), s"Use at least one ascii character like '#' or '*'. $universalPasswordInstruction"),
    ),
    is(a.contains("poop"), "Really!")
  )
}

val userValidator = new Validator[(String, String), (Int, String)] {
  override def validate(a: (String, String)): Seq[(Int, String)] = checkAll(
    is(a._1.length > 0, (0, "Username is empty!")),
  ) ++ passwordValidator.validate(a._2).map(x => (1, x))
}

//use
userValidator.validate("SomeUserName" -> "SomePassword") match {
  case Seq() => //OK case
  case errors => //deal with it
}
```

Maybe not so fancy but works for me :). Code is simple and rather self explanatory. Nulls here are just implementation detail (they doesn't show up in usercode, and can be switched to Options).

Comment: that's great, in my next project I'm definitely going to use Validator